Can I use a desktop computer in Bangladesh?
I have purchased a desktop computer in Poland.
I want to take it to Bangladesh.
Do I have to change the power box, or can I use the same power box?


While it doesn't change much the main points of the answer, for details, can you tell us if the power supply is internal (there's just a cable from the power socket to the PC) or external (there's an external box)? You could also add a picture of the plate that should appear on either which states voltages, amperages, frequency, etc. A picture of the various plugs could also help pointing you to the right adapters.

@jcaron, https://allegro.pl/oferta/zasilacz-do-komputera-gigabyte-p650g-650w-80-gold-atx-120mm-czarny-16546700451

You need to check the specification on you desktop power supply. Almost all of them these days are "universal", i.e. they will say something like 100V-240V 50/60Hz. Bangladesh has (officially) 220V and 50 Hz. As long as that's within the specs for your power supply, you are fine.
You will still need a convertible passive plug adaptor since Bangladesh uses multiple types of AC outlets most of which are not compatible with Poland. See for example https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/us/bangladesh/
Update based on specs.
The specs look fine

However 650W is a lot of power for a travel adapter. While they are typically rated for that power the tend to make mechanically poor connections and may wiggle and fall out, which can result in significant sparking and brown outs.
Per the comment Weather Vane: your power supply as an IEC connector and I would recommend getting a dedicated IEC power chord that fits the outlet you need to use in Bangladesh.

...or just buy a power cord locally, since they just plug into the desktop PC.

@WeatherVane Many desktop PCs use external power supplies these days, especially the smaller ones. There's still often a replaceable power cord that goes into that external power supply, but the plug is slightly less standard than what you can find on internal power supplies.

Once upon a time some internal desktop power supplies had a physical switch to select 110 or 220 V. Haven't seen one in a while though, not sure that still exists.

@jcaron I haven't seen a desktop PC with external pwer supply, but I know that trend for printers etc. where it's easier to make low-voltage kit, with less stringent safety conditions.

@WeatherVane For those I have seen (NUCs, Dell Optiplex Micro Form Factor...) it's probably more a matter of size and maybe heat dissipation than anything else, but it's possible there are other reasons.

@jcaron Essentially the switches dissapeared because voltage doubling rectifiers were replaced by active power factor correction circuits. AIUI Europe now essentially mandates active power factor correction for desktop PC sized power supplies, and the higher power levels of modern PCs have also made it highly desirable to keep the input current down.
